# Dynamic vertical RecyclerView inside viewHolder of vertical recyclerview causes outer RecyclerView to lag on first scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, optimization, android-recyclerview, ui-thread

I'm working on an app which has social media like feed.
Feed consists of regular **news like posts** (*cover image, likes, comments, author, text content etc.*)
and
**poll like posts** -  its just like news post but instead of cover image you are presented with   several options for a question to choose from.
Example that come to my mind is **youtube**, there when scrolling you see videos, just pictures   with text, and surveys with options sometimes. I'll add screenshot for better understanding.

**RV** - `RecyclerView`, **VH** - `ViewHolder`

**GOAL**:
Vertical `RV` with `VH` containing dynamic number of vertical views, lets say the number of views ranges from `1` to `10`.

**IMPLEMENTAION**: Put inside VH of outer `RV` inner vertical `RV` and submit new list to inner `RV` adapter inside of `onBindViewHolder()` of outer `RV`.

**PROBLEM**:
Lag on scroll of `outer RV` caused by inflation of `VHs` for `inner RV`.
It's because `RV` creates `VHs` on demand as user scrolls and when scroll happens `VH` for outer `RV` created which in turn triggers inflation of `VHs` for `inner RV` and its the main cause of lag.
The culprit is the inflation for sure because lag occurs only on first scroll of `5-7 VHs` and it's gone, which means rebinding is lightweight task.

**SOLUTION ATTEMPTS SO FAR**:

- (Failed) Make inner `RVs` use shared `RecycledViewPool`. Because it's needed to inflate about `15` inner `VHs` before even starting to reuse views in shared pool.
- (Failed) Experimented with ditching inner `RV` completely and instead have a `custom view` with `10` views added in `xml layout` and make then `gone/visible` based on required number.=They still need to be inflated, duh..
- (Semi working) Prepopulate `RecycledViewPool` used by inner `RVs` the moment `adapter` of outer `RV` gets attached and clear when gets detached.
  This allowed inner `RVs` to start using `VHs` from shared pool right away.
  The horrible lag seems to be almost completely gone, almost.
  But it feels really wrong for some reason, plus I have to set my inner `VH's` `itemViewType` to `-1` for it to work.

```
       private val recycledViewPool: RecycledViewPool by lazy {
            RecycledViewPool().apply {
                setMaxRecycledViews(-1, 30)
            }
        }

        override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
            recycledViewPool.clear()
            for (i in 0..30) {
                recycledViewPool.putRecycledView(
                    PollResultOptionVH.create(recyclerView)
                )
            }
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        }

        override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
            super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)
            recycledViewPool.clear()
        }
```

**REMAINING PROBLEM:**
Although big chunk of lagging is gone there is another problem now - when scrolling outer `RV` you can feel that its still not completely smooth, as if some operation is till taking longer than `16ms`, like micro jitters. As if taking pre inflated views from shared `RecycledViewPool` is still taking some time and effort.  The problem is only on first scroll..

**QUESTION:**
Can anyone suggest alternative to my solution?
What could be the reason that there is still some jitter?
Any other optimization suggestions, for my outer `RV` to scroll smoothly?
I know there is solution out there because there are many social media apps with muck more complex `VHs` that work really smooth, but I couldn't find any.

[image: Youtube example]

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult to diagnose your issue without the actual code. I'll share a few solutions and ideas about what might be happening. I want you to go through these and see if anything helps you figure out your issue.

**#1 "Lagging" when scrolling or "lagging" when loading**

I'm not sure if you mean that the lagging appears when the RV adapter loads data for the first time or if it appears when you start scrolling. If it appears when you start scrolling, I'd recommend you double-check a few things:

- The data doesn't come from a computed property. Using a computed property that generates the data every time you fetch an item might be the source of the lag. For example:

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
  private val myRawListData = mutableListOf<Data>()
  
  fun setData(list: List<Data>) {
    myRawListData.clear()
    myRawListData.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
  
  private val myListData : List<SomeOtherDataStructure>
    get() {
      return myRawListData.groupBy { 
        // Transform your data structure into something else
      }
    }
  
  
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val dataItem = myListData[position] // This call will trigger the computation above everytime
  }
  //...
```

If you have something like the above, I'd recommend you to process the data only once instead of relying on computed properties.

**#2 The poll-like view**

I think this is most likely what is causing the issue. I'd recommend *not* using an inner RV no matter what, it might not just cause issues with the scrolling, but you might get issues when the VH gets recycled. If you disable the recycling pool so none of the items actually gets recycled, you are basically using a `LinearLayout` with that in mind, why don't we just use a custom view? For example:

```
class CustomStylingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCustomStylingBinding
    private val adapter by lazy {
        MyNewsAdapter(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCustomStylingBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.newsRv.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setNewsItems(generateRandomData())
    }

    private fun generateRandomData(): List<Any> {
        return mutableListOf<Any>().apply {
           repeat(3000) {
               add(News(title = "Title #$it", body = "#$it Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum"))
               add(PollPost(title = "Poll #$it", options = mutableListOf<String>().apply {
                    repeat((0..10).random()) {
                        add("Random Option #$it")
                    }
               }))
           }
        }
    }
}

class MyNewsAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    // Ideally if you have some sort of unique id, go with a RecyclerView.ListAdapter
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    // Using Any might look like an anti-pattern but in my experience when you have adapters
    // like this with so many different viewTypes, it makes things much more flexible.
    private val newsItems = mutableListOf<Any>()

    private class PollViewHolder(val binding: ViewHolderPollBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    private class NewsViewHolder(val binding: ViewHolderNewsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (newsItems[position]) {
            is News -> VIEW_TYPE_NEWS
            is PollPost -> VIEW_TYPE_POLL
            else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown item")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_POLL -> {
                PollViewHolder(
                    ViewHolderPollBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                )
            }
            VIEW_TYPE_NEWS -> {
                NewsViewHolder(
                    ViewHolderNewsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                )
            }
            else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown view")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = newsItems[position]
        when (holder) {
            is NewsViewHolder -> onBindNewsViewHolder(holder, item as News, position)
            is PollViewHolder -> onBindPollViewHolder(holder, item as PollPost, position)
        }
    }

    private fun onBindPollViewHolder(
        holder: PollViewHolder,
        pollPost: PollPost,
        position: Int
    ) {
        holder.binding.titleTv.text = pollPost.title
        holder.binding.poll.setItems(pollPost.options)
        holder.binding.poll.setOnPollOptionClicked { index, str ->
            // You can expose this back to the activity through another callback interface
            Toast.makeText(context, "Option #$index Clicked -> $str", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun onBindNewsViewHolder(
        holder: NewsViewHolder,
        news: News,
        position: Int
    ) {
        holder.binding.titleTv.text = news.title
        holder.binding.bodyTv.text = news.body
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = newsItems.size
    fun setNewsItems(data: List<Any>) {
        newsItems.clear()
        newsItems.addAll(data)
        // Again, if you can use ListAdapter even better!
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val VIEW_TYPE_NEWS = 100
        private const val VIEW_TYPE_POLL = 200
    }
}


data class News(
    val title: String,
    val body: String,
)

data class PollPost(
    val title: String,
    val options: List<String>
)
```

The `PollView` looks like this:

```
package com.appsamurai.storylydemo

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.appsamurai.storylydemo.databinding.ViewPollBinding

open class PollView : LinearLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        onInflate(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        onInflate(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        onInflate(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        onInflate(context)
    }

    private val bindings by lazy {
        ViewPollBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
    }

    private val items = mutableListOf<String>()

    private val allOptTextViews : List<TextView>
        get() = listOf(bindings.opt1, bindings.opt2, bindings.opt3, bindings.opt4, bindings.opt5,
            bindings.opt6, bindings.opt7, bindings.opt8, bindings.opt9, bindings.opt10)

    private fun onInflate(context: Context) {
        allOptTextViews.forEachIndexed { index, textView ->
            textView.setOnClickListener {
                callback(index, items[index])
            }
        }
    }

    private var callback : ((Int, String) -> Unit) = {_, _ -> } // Default init

    fun setOnPollOptionClicked(func: ((Int, String) -> Unit)) {
        callback = func
    }

    fun setItems(options: List<String>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(options)
        allOptTextViews.forEachIndexed { index, textView ->
            val option = items.getOrNull(index)
            if (option.isNullOrBlank()) {
                textView.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                textView.text = option
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the XMLs

The `view_holder_poll.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:id="@+id/title_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.appsamurai.storylydemo.PollView
        android:id="@+id/poll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `view_poll.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt2"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt3"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt4"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt5"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt6"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt7"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt8"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt9"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opt10"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:text="Option #1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `view_holder_news.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        tools:text="Title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:id="@+id/title_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        tools:text="Body"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:id="@+id/body_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the `activity_custom_styling.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomStylingActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_rv"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejHFF.jpg

Now, notice a few things, I assumed you have a max of 10 options, if that isn't the case, then the only other solution would be to dinamically add the views into the `LinearLayout` – if it is possible for you to get a fixed amount of options, even better, that would make the implementation much simpler.

But see that the "dynamic" custom view does not cause any lagging. The lagging you are experiencing might also come from other places. Are you loading any images using Glide/Picasso? Do you stop any rendering of those images if the ViewHolder gets scrolled away? Are you loading YouTube videos?

If you have any more info, I'd be happy to drop some more feedback. I hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for you your detailed answer! Regarding your first theory,  data comes already computed, and I doubt that any computation would be significant enough to cause lag (unless bitmaps, lists of length in millions). Regarding, you second suggestion, as i stated in my question i already tried that approach and failed(

Comment: can you run you own code and confirm that you dont have any lags? Outer RVs VH must almost full screen.

Comment: **Regarding your first theory, data comes already computed, and I doubt that any computation would be significant enough to cause lag (unless bitmaps, lists of length in millions).**

Don't be so sure about that, doing a `groupBy` in a collection would be enough to see some lag.
**can you run you own code and confirm that you dont have any lags?**
Sorry, I don't follow, I submitted a gif of the code above and how it looks like when running.

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't notice the gif, but the thing is you are scrolling really fast :) to notice4 the lag you have scroll slowly, as if you were going through instagram or something of that sort. Even before my own optimisations when lag wsss at its worst fast flings would make unnoticable..

Comment: Anyway I don't want the bounty got to waste so i wanna award you just for your time and effort. I appreciate that, thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, okay I might have misunderstood what you mean by "lag". I thought the lag you were talking about was a slowness during scrolling. Are you saying that the lag appears when rendering the ViewHolders? Q: Do you have a fixed amount of options in the "PollView" or do you need to load an indefinite amount of options?